# Basics operation with WSO2 Carbon

Tags: wso2

I'm new in this area followed all the steps for installing WSO2 Business Process Server and the whole process to use the eclipse.

I did the Quick-Start Guide - Modeling a Process according to the oriented, but even doing it as quick-start recommends, but I could not make that happen and deploy the portal or the zip package to get on the portal is generated

**This errors occurred**

```
"No properties path set - looking for transactions.properties in classpath...
Using init file: /C:/wso2bps-2.1.2/lib/transactions.properties"
```

**And**

```
"ERROR - Http11NioProtocol - Failed to start end point associated with ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-9944"]
java.net.BindException: Address already in use: bind"
```

I would like to help to solve these problems and move on.

Sorry if I was not very technical, and I was not very clear, but I could capture was to pass

Tks

Michel Antunes

Answer (score 1):

Please refer to the WSO2 BPS [installation guide](http://wso2.org/project/bps/2.1.2/docs/bpel-installation-guide/bpel_installation_guide.html#WSO2-Business-Process-Server-Installation-Guide).
And also make sure, port 9944 is not used by some other process.

You can change the port offset value in carbon.xml (CARBON_HOME/repository/conf).

```
<Offset>1</Offset>
```

Offset moves all ports by the given value.

Hope this helps.

Thanks

Thilini